# Как продолжить исполнение кода, но не закрывая формы

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter

Ребят всем привет! Прошу помощи!!! есть код (по сути не важно что там) если код отрабатывает, то выскакивает форма, и пока эту форму не закроешь, код работать дальше не будет, а задача такова, что не зависимо от того открыта форма или нет, код дальше должен работать. пробовал и threading и asyngio, и чот не получается. хелп-ме!
#код формы

```
def tkForm(mac):
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x100")
root.title("!!!!!!!!!")
label = Label(text= mac, pady=100)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

#вызов функции

```
threadTkForm = threading.Thread(target=tkForm(mac))
threadTkForm.start()
```

Comment: Что не получается? Приведите код.

Comment: добавил, вроде ни чего не упустил

Comment: Ну вам наверное наоборот надо какие-то вычисления делать в новом треде, а не GUI рисовать. GUI рисует основной тред как-раз.

Comment: сначала хотел поспорить, а потом прикинул и правда, хотя ввы может идею не поняли, но ваша мысль здравая! спасибо!!!!